# Counting turtles on a colored patch in Netlogo

Tags: netlogo

I am trying to count the turtles that are on a black/greyish patch with the colorcode 1.
This is what I have come up with so far:

```
 ask turtles [
    let patchThere patch-here
    if pcolor of patchThere = 1 [
      set carsOnIntersection carsOnIntersection + 1
    ] 
   ]
```

So I am trying to see what number of turtles is on a patch with color 1. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You haven't explained what it is doing wrong - is the total incorrect, is there an error message etc? But `pcolor of` needs to be `[pcolor] of`. You might also want to consider doing this from the perspective of the patches, and count the turtles on the relevant patches instead of asking every turtle what coloured patch it is standing on

Comment: Hi yeah that worked, thanks. I should have put the error there yes. Sorry. So how would I ask the patches it there is a turtle there?

Comment: look at `count`, `any?` and `turtles-here` in the NetLogo dictionary